# CSS not finding JavaFX rules

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I am currently trying to style my JavaFX project with CSS, and each time I try to implement a property, it says "no rule for ___ found!". I have tried -fx-font-family: and -fx-background-color:.

I am using Eclipse 2019-09.

EDIT: Minimal Reproductive Example: application.css in a JavaFX project in Eclipse 2019-09

`.label {
    -fx-font-family: Helvetica;
}`

Shows the message "no rule for -fx-font-family found!" and underlines the -fx-font-family line in yellow.

Comment: What does "___" usually say?

Comment: Can you add the CSS file(s) to the scene graph without issue? If so, then this is probably just a problem with your IDE. Have you tried installing [e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)?

Comment: do what Slaw suggested and also edit your buildpath to include javafx, to enable jfx-css code-assistance

Comment: I have e(fx)clipse installed and working, (except this part obviously). "___" says the rule I attempted to use: Ex. "no rule for -fx-font-family found!"

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Auto-completion was not working in JavaFx-Projects' css files.

I am using: openJDK12.0.2 and openjfx-sdk-11

The Problem is that e(fx)clipse requires this file in the build path.
**/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.5.0.201907240300.jar**

Earlier versions automatically added a JavaFX-Library (which included this jar) to your JavaFX-Project.

For using openjfx-sdk-11 you need to define a User Library anyways. I called it JavaFX11. Add all the JavaFX.***.jars there and also the **org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.5.0.201907240300.jar.**

Having a modularised project, you need to rename the file to some name, where the module system can derive a module name from. Ergo:
**org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8.jar**

Now, auto-completion should work for all JavaFX-Projects where you used the JavaFX11-User-Library again!

Hope that helps.
Johannes